# Add new playlist to selected tracks

Tags: pro-tools

In Pro Tools, I can add a new playlist to a single track using the track's Playlist menu:
[image]

And if I hold down `option` it will create a new playlist for all tracks in the session.

How do I create a new playlist just in the selected tracks?  Or, as an alternative, for all tracks in a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI BenV

If you hold down Shift+Alt it serves as an "apply to all selected" Same for solos, comping, applying inserts, sends, etc.

Comment: After adapting this to Shift+Opt for Mac, worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi BenV... Yes, sorry shift+opt I'm getting used to my new mac keyboard which puts an "alt" on there!

Comment: Protools 9 tip: have the tracks selected and press ctrl+\
I think it's ctrl anyway can never remember w/out actually be on the spot doing soemthing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, I think you just need to group the tracks, make sure the group is enabled, and then make a new playlist as usual.

Comment: Does it matter if it's a Mix group vs an Edit group?